# Python use implicit argument instead of explicit

Tags: python, class

Haii, I'm new to python.
I have this dummy code:

```
class Reader:

  def __init__(self, a_list):
    self.a_list = a_list

  def read(self):
    s = "The list reads as such:"
    for index, value in enumerate(self.a_list, start=1):
      s = s + "\n  element number {} is:  {}".format(index, value)
    print(s)
```

I want to know how can I use:

```
["haii", "my", "name", "is", "Jhon"].read()
```

instead of:

```
Reader(["haii", "my", "name", "is", "Jhon"]).read()
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your goal is,  could you elaborate a little bit on that. Do you want to create an own `read` function that is called instead of the original `read` function when you use it on a `list`? If you have your own fuction you could use it like `read(["haii", "my"]) `. Is that an option?

Comment: `[...]` cannot be overloaded to produce something other than an instance of `list`, and you cannot add methods to the built-in `list` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you wanted `[].read()` won't work but `list([]).read()` will.

**Also Note:** This is highly unrecommended! Changing built in types can have terrible consequences. Your `Reader` wrapper was the best way to do it.

```
class MyList(list):
    def read(self):
        s = "The list reads as such:"
        for index, value in enumerate(self, start=1):
            s = s + "\n  element number {} is:  {}".format(index, value)
        print(s)


list = MyList
lst = list(["haii", "my", "name", "is", "Jhon"])
lst.read()
```

Comment: `list = MyList` doens't server any real purpose. As long as you need to use *some* wrapper around `[...]`, it surely doesn't matter if the name is `list` or `MyList`. Extending `list` on its own is fine.

Comment: Yea that ways his Reader wrapper itself worked just fine. But I wonder why this code works with list([]).read() and doesn't work with [].read().

Comment: what have you done which is different from mine solution ?

Comment: @AliHasanAhmedKhan list is a built in class. I override that list class. That's the main difference. Next is I assign the built in class to my new class. Rest is somewhat similar.

Comment: Because you reassigned the name `list` to your custom subclass of `list`. `[]` is not shorthand for whatever `list()` returns; it is hard-coded to produce an instance of `__builtins__.list`, which is what `list` refers to if you don't change its value.

Comment: Idea is the same. may be what you did is not recommended as you said.

Answer (score 1):

you can not use this `["haii", "my", "name", "is", "Jhon"].read()`. But you can use this `read(["haii", "my", "name", "is", "Jhon"])` by adding an argument in `read` function.

```
class Reader:

  def read(self, list1):
    s = "The list reads as such:"
    for index, value in enumerate(list1, start=1):
      s = s + "\n  element number {} is:  {}".format(index, value)
    print(s)


Obj = Reader()

Obj.read(["haii", "my", "name", "is", "Jhon"])
```

Comment: The class here serves no purpose. `Reader.read` may as well be an ordinary function.

Comment: In his original code there was a class, i know about what you are saying

Comment: The original code, at least, used `self` to hold a reference to the list that `read` iterates over. By ignoring `self` and passing a list directly to `read`, you threw out any reason to preserve the class.

Comment: It is necessary to use self whenever we use class ?

Comment: Why define a class if you don't? `def read(list1):...` and `read([...])` will work exactly the same, without bothering with the trouble of defining a new class and instantiating it.

Comment: just have some similarity with the original code, because he is new in python.

Comment: Showing him an irregular use of a class isn't going to help. The original question was how to *get rid of* the class, anyway (not that you can in the way they wanted).

Comment: Its irregular for you and me not for him. Time to time he will get learned

Comment: There's no reason that time can't be *now*.